# Couchapp, Jquery: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, couchapp

Getting unexpected identifier error in line 12 while writing a couchapp 
I am trying to call a javascript function in recordedit.js when anyone clicks on add item link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Items </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/main.css" type="text/css">
<script src= "vendor/couchapp/loader.js"></script>
<script src= "recordedit.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
updateItems();
}
$("a.add").live('click', fucntion(event){itemform();});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="store"></div>
<h1>Store</h1>
<div id="items"><div id="additem"><a href="#" class="add">Add Item</a></div>
<div id="all"></div>
<div id="itemform"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fucntion` is miss spelled, and you are not including your jQuery? Or is that within the loader?

Should be:

```
$("a.add").live('click', function(event){itemform();});
```

Comment: Thank you. It is within loader.js

Comment: Also missing close bracket `)` at the end of `$(document).ready(`

Comment: Thank you. That did it. Can't upvote though, do not have enough karma :)